# Rewrite a query string to path using mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to know how can I rewrite the following URLs:

```
http://domain.com/folder/subfolder/?id=145&post_id=12
http://domain.com/folder/subfolder2/?id=146&post_id=13
http://domain.com/folder/subfolder3/?id=147&post_id=14
```

to:

```
http ://domain.com/folder/subfolder/145/12
http ://domain.com/folder/subfolder2/146/13
http ://domain.com/folder/subfolder3/147/14
```

Thankful for any help.

Comment: I tried alot of htaccess codes but I couldn't get what I want

Comment: I want to keep the requested folders the same I want to rewrite just the query string to a path too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/s7a3s4/f6/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s7a3s4/f6/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(\d+)/?$ $1/?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ $1/?id=$2&post_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: hey anubhava can you help me?

Comment: hello here is my url for example : http://domain.com/folder/subfolder3/?id=147 I want to change only ?id=147 to http://domain.com/folder/subfolder3/147 so for example http://domain.com/folder/subfolder2/147.

Comment: So `subfolder3` is becoming `subfolder2` os that a typo?

Comment: I mean I want to keep same folders I want to rewrite query string to path too

Comment: here is what I want to do : http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/en/?i=1893 http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/ar/?i=1893 http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/fr/?i=1893 http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/es/?i=1893 to http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/en/1893http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/ar/1893http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/fr/1893

Comment: see updated answer. `.htaccess` must be placed in `/s7a3s4/f6/` directory and URL that you need to enter is this: `http://gols.com/s7a3s4/f6/ar/1893`.